# How does Sitecore determine which EventQueue database to use for a given event and how to change it

Tags: publishing, events, event-queue

Sitecore 8.2

I have a CM and 2 CDs like so:

```
                                   ___ CD1 (web1, core)
CM (master, core, web1, web2) ____/
                                  \___ CD2 (web2, core2)
```

***Note that `core` is shared by CM and CD1, but not CD2.***

When I publish from CM to both CDs, Sitecore "knows" to put the `publish:end:remote` event in *both* web1 and web2 database EventQueue tables. It does *not* put it in the `core` EventQueue table, which is the default eventing provider as defined in the config:

```
<eventing defaultProvider="sitecore">    
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Eventing.EventProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" systemDatabaseName="core"/>
    </providers>
    ...
</eventing>
```

Interestingly, the `publish:complete:remote` event does not behave the same way: it goes straight to the `core` database EventQueue table.

I've tried decompiling the Sitecore assemblies and can't find where there's any kind of switch that says "raise event X in database Y". It's just "raise event X". I'm sure I'm missing something.

#### How does Sitecore know to put one type of event (`publish:end:remote`) in each `web` database and another (`publish:complete:remote`) in `core`?